# RSweave: How to copy/paste from pdf to notepad avoiding error?

Tags: r, encoding

I compile a latex document which contains accents ("é" for instance) using RSweave. Then I copy the text from the pdf generated by pdflatex in a notepad. The resulting shows strange characters, for some encoding reason.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

**Minimal working example**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=FALSE}

Orçamentária \\
Tendência \\
saída \\
gestão \\
órgão \\
coração 

\end{document}
```

**When I copy this words from pdf to notepad (pdf open in Adobe Reader), I get:**

Orcamentaria
Tend^encia
sada
gest~ao
org~ao
corac~ao

[The real output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN82S.png)

Comment: Try adding \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and \usepackage{lmodern} before \begin{document}

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search a lot, I discover the source of problem. In C:\Users...\Documents\R\R-3.1.2\share\texmf\tex\latex\Sweave.sty there is:

```
 \ifthenelse{\boolean{Sweave@ae}}{%
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \RequirePackage{ae}
}{}%
```

According to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts :

*The package ae (almost European) is obsolete. It provided some workarounds for hyphenation of words with special characters. These are not necessary any more with fonts like lmodern. Using the ae package leads to text encoding problems in PDF files generated via pdflatex (e.g. text extraction and searching), besides typographic issues.*

So, if I comment this line in Sweave.sty I solve the problem. Or just comment \userpackage{sweave} in .tex file.